# How to diagnose a bad stator?

Tags: ignition, yamaha, stator, polaris, sportsman

Consider the following diagram :
This is for a Polaris sportsman 700 2003 ATV

[image]

On the top right corner, you have the information to check if the stator function properly.

For the first three coils, everything pass.

However, I'm not sure how to test the **ignition coil** as the only data specified are *"without caps"* and *"with caps"*.

Which *"caps"* do the diagram refer to and how can I properly test the ignition coil ?

Also, the main reason why I'm checking if my stator does work properly is because I get no spark when starting and I'm trying to figure out why. Keeping this in mind, I don't think I have to check the *"front wheel drive coil"* and the *"battery charge coil"*, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ATV has a twin cylinder engine. I believe the "caps" they are referring to in the diagram are the caps which go onto the coil leads. You need to test the coil resistance through the spark plug leads, with and without the caps. The caps are the part which screws into the spark plug lead and attaches it to the spark plug. [Here is a video](https://youtu.be/ix9YhKnYVqs?t=6m50s) which explains it on a single cylinder ATV, though the procedure should be basically the same for yours. I've put the video at the spot where he's testing the coil. (**NOTE:** You can watch the entire video, but this guy is *painfully* slow ... your choice.)

> Keeping this in mind, I don't think I have to check the "front wheel drive coil" and the "battery charge coil", right ?

I wouldn't think so either.